# Events are getting deleted in 10 secs from google calendar : Android

Tags: android, calendar, google-calendar-api, uri

I am trying to add events to google calendar by below code :

```
        val calendar = Calendar.getInstance()
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 18)
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 30)
        val values = ContentValues()
        values.put(CalendarContract.Events.DTSTART, calendar.timeInMillis)
        calendar.add(Calendar.HOUR, 1)
        values.put(CalendarContract.Events.DTEND, calendar.timeInMillis)
        values.put(CalendarContract.Events.TITLE, "meetingInfo.title")
        values.put(CalendarContract.Events.DESCRIPTION, "meetingInfo.description")
        values.put(CalendarContract.Events.EVENT_LOCATION, "meetingInfo.location")
        val timeZone = TimeZone.getDefault()
        values.put(CalendarContract.Events.ALL_DAY, false)
        values.put(CalendarContract.Events.EVENT_TIMEZONE, timeZone.id)
        values.put(CalendarContract.Events.RRULE, "FREQ=YEARLY");
        values.put(CalendarContract.Events.CALENDAR_ID, 1)
        contentResolver.insert(CalendarContract.Events.CONTENT_URI, values)
```

I have given both permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALENDAR" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR" />
```

but after adding this event it's appearing for sometime after 10 sec it's getting deleted.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Please try with below following code. which is working code for me. Its in kotlin

```
        val date = it.getDateformated() -> geting date from viewmodel
        val day = it.getDayOfMonth() -> geting day of month from viewmodel
        val month = it.getMonth() -> geting month from viewmodel
        val year = it.getYear() -> geting year from viewmodel
```

```html
val calendarIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSERT)
calendarIntent.data = CalendarContract.Events.CONTENT_URI

calendarIntent.type = "vnd.android.cursor.item/event"
calendarIntent.putExtra(Events.TITLE, getString(R.string.signings_calendar_title))
calendarIntent.putExtra(
    Events.DESCRIPTION,
    mViewModel.instructions
)
mViewModel.dateInfo.value?.let {
    calendarIntent.putExtra(
        Events.EVENT_LOCATION,
        it.getAddress()
    )

    it.ViewedDate?.let { ViewedDatetemp->
       

            val date = it.getDateformated()
            val day = it.getDayOfMonth()
            val month = it.getMonth()
            val year = it.getYear()

            val calDate = GregorianCalendar(year!!, month!!, day!!)
            calendarIntent.putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_ALL_DAY, false)
            calendarIntent.putExtra(
                CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_BEGIN_TIME,
                calDate.timeInMillis
            )
            calendarIntent.putExtra(
                CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_END_TIME,
                calDate.timeInMillis + 60 * 60 * 1000
            )
        
    }
}

calendarIntent.putExtra(Events.ALLOWED_REMINDERS, true)

startActivity(calendarIntent)
```

Comment: Thanks for answer but this will open calendar activity which I don't want to open.

Comment: Hi, by using content resolver we can able to fetch all calendar info and we can do whatever we want, but while inserting it will cause some problem

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/calendar-provider

Comment: I got the solution, I will share it here once I will do complete my testing.